# Copy Rotation Constraint with Offset doesn't work like expected

Tags: rigging, armature, constraints

Trying to constraint deform armature with bad bone rotations to a copied but fixed armature with proper bone rotations for animation. Some kind of puppetering. (I can't change position or hierarchy of a deform armature, because of my reasons)
The problem is when i try to copy rotation:

1. The Bone I copy rotation to, snaps to exact same rotation as it's parent (but want it to stay in the original place), Rotation behaviour is fine, like if it was direct parented
2. Tried fixing it with Local Space - Local Space. Bone snapped to it's original rotation, but... When i try to rotate the parent, child goes to opposite rotation, depending on the axis of the parent i rotate. Totally not what i want. I rotate parent up, child goes left and down or something like that. Tried all possible combinations of invert XZY axies, mixes, target-owner, Legacy Offset. Nothing works.
3. Tried Child-Of, it works, but double transformation ruins it for my pipeline.

What i expected:
I wanted to parent one bone to another, but with COPY ROTATION Constraint (with child keeping it's original rotation). Its so easy to do in maya. You just tick the Offset option.

[image]
https://youtu.be/zX9vLTbFnB0

Comment: Hello, could you please reproduce the case on a simple armature, show pictures and share the armature so that we can test? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @moonboots I added .Blend + video example

Comment: maybe you should draw what you want to achieve, with several drawings, perhaps it will make it clearer (at least for me)

Comment: @moonboots https://puu.sh/GyKfj/baeee1aad7.mp4
I want left armature to move like this new i created. (but i need to do this with Constraints only)

Comment: @moonboots https://puu.sh/GyKon/8a0e500b4d.mp4 Colored to be more clear.
Orange - Separate Armature (bad bone orients) that deforms the mesh.
Green - Separate Fixed Armature (good bone rotations) that should control bad armature. (For animation)

Comment: If I understand correctly, you should first make sure that the bones have the same orientation: display the axis of the armature, select each bone of the controlled armature and ctrl R to rotate 180°, also rotate a bit the controller bones so that they are correctly aligned... Tell me if that was your problem...

Comment: here is what it gives if bones are aligned: https://zupimages.net/up/20/40/v0ia.gif

Comment: @moonboots I cannot change anything in original armature ( bone rotations, bone hierarchy) I must keep original skeleton as it is and Animate it. And since i cannot put IK controllers on it and so on (because how badly bones rotations are), i decided to make a copy of this armature, fix rotation of all bones and then parent each bone of an original to a new. So i can animate Good armature and it will transfer animation to original armature.
If i fix bone rotations on original armature, then all animations produced by this rig will be crooked when i import them in my unreal engine scene.